# Yearling badge awarded too often?

Tags: bug, badges

I was just awarded the "Yearling" badge on MSE for the fifth time in the past month. I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening. A screenshot is provided as evidence.

[image: screenshot]

My account was created a pretty long while ago, but I only recently started posting--perhaps that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the correct number of badges you should have is $$\max\{n\leq\text{Years}\mid n\times200\leq\text{Reputation}\}.$$

If you just passed a threshold, you might get more badges.

Comment: So yearling compares total years and total reputation, rather than (as I interpreted from the badge description) counting the distinct year-long periods with at least +200 reputation gain?

Comment: Does this mean that if user $X$ earns 0 reputation in the first 10 years, and then earns 2000 reputation in the first month of the 11th year, they will be awarded 10 “yearling” batches in that month?

Comment: @MJD: Yes. If you have an inactive account which is a decade old, then for ten days you get 200 points per day (which is the maximum), then you will get a badge every day.

Comment: @MJD  Clearly not ideal in any way, shape or form. ... Definitley Worth a post to meta.se, methinks,

Comment: @amWhy I suspect that this is a case of SE not saving yearly reputation in a permanent database rather than a deliberate design decision.